# Original article on the Grothendieck group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, grothendieck-construction

Is there someone who knows the title of the original publication of Grothendieck on the construction of the [Grothendieck group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What seems to be clear is that the origin of the Grothendieck group is Grothendieck's work on Riemann-Roch's theorem around 1956.

According to Weibel's [*The Development of Algebraic K-theory before 1980*](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/papers-dir/khistory.pdf) (which is certainly worth reading!), the original source is *Classes de faisceaux et théorème de Riemann-Roch*, some mimeographed notes from 1957 who were later published (in 1971) in *Théorie des intersections et théorème de Riemann-Roch (SGA6)*.

In his [Lecture Notes on Algebraic K-theory](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/kurs/mat9570v10/akt.pdf), Rognes links to Borel and Serre, *Le théorème de Riemann-Roch*, Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France **86** (1958) “for the published exposition.”